# Let $\mathcal{L} =\{x+iy:x,y\in \mathbb{R},F(x,y)=0 \}$ is algebraic curve. How Can we prove, $\mathcal{L}$ is a piecewise $C^\infty$curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose

- $F(x,y)$ is polynomial .
- $\mathcal{L} =\{x+iy:x,y\in \mathbb{R},F(x,y)=0 \}$ .
- We know that ${\cal L}$ is algebraic curve.

How Can we prove, $\mathcal{L}$ is a piecewise $C^\infty$curve, and it has **at most a finite number** of points, where the tangent fails
to exist?

Comment: What do you mean by algebraic curve? Why are you considering $\mathcal L$ in $\Bbb C$ rather than in $\Bbb R^2$? ... Do you know the Implicit Function Theorem? What does it tell you about the curve $F(x,y)=0$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin - Thank you, I need a reference about ' Implicit Function Theorem'.

Comment: Every textbook on multivariate calculus.

Comment: @TedShifrin - Which reference says that " an algebraic curve is the union of finitely many (irreducible) branches"?

Comment: If you're doing algebraic geometry with the complex numbers, you've phrased the question wrong. If this is an exercise using the Implicit Function Theorem (and to know where $F=0$ may fail to define a submanifold), you should look up that theorem. You can start with wikipedia by yourself.

Comment: @TedShifrin - I don't understand, Why does "at most a finite number of points"?